# Solaris: IP Spoofing Across Ethernet Ports

Tags: network, ip-spoofing, routing

Given a Solaris machine with two network interfaces corresponding to the separate ethernet ports in the back.

- 0: `192.168.0.5`/`255.255.255.0`
- 1: `192.168.1.5`/`255.255.255.0`

with `/etc/defaultrouter` set to `192.168.0.1`

If a connection (either TCP or UDP) comes in on port 0, but it is from `192.168.1.6` (obviously spoofed), does that mean that any responses (the `SYN-ACK` packet in the case of a TCP server, or the DNS response in case of a DNS server) will be sent out on port 1 (due to the IP address).

Or will they be dropped, or worse, will they be sent back out on port 0?

I am attempting to asses the risk of IP spoofing across physical interfaces. If a server listens on all interfaces, but only authorizes connections from `192.168.1.*`, I want to know how likely it is that it will accept connections from the wrong port.

Hypothetical threat environment: port 1 is connected to trusted, non-internet network. Port 0's subnet might have a compromised machine on it.

Comment: If port 0 is connected to the internet it can not have a 192.168.x.x address

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to explain this in any more detail, but the Linux kernel has the functionality to track network connections (allowing for stateful inspection in firewalls).  I would doubt that this is that much of a risk, but the easiest way to see is to test it... spin up an example with virtual machines and see what happens.

Comment: P.S. are  you looking at this issue within proprietary code or is this in regards to an already established service/application?

Comment: also, your firewall and IDS should pick this up fairly easy.

Comment: @this.josh: This is hypothetical. In the example, the server is behind a NAT with port forwarding for the necessary services.

Comment: @Ormis: The code that starts the TCP or UDP servers would be proprietary. I think you have a good point. When we set up ipfilter, perhaps it will lock down by interface.

Comment: If i remember correctly, it should be as simple as....

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP

Comment: Is this machine serving requests from the internet or do you assume it will only recieve replies from packets it sends out?

Comment: @this.josh, The machine does have another service that only listens on ethernet port 0. But that is not part of this question. The service in question will receive requests from both interfaces, but it needs to know which interface it came from.

Comment: @Ormis, Please make an answer out of your last question. I think it is worth some up-votes.

Comment: If the NAT is doing some type of restricted translation, then you can restrict translated packets to allow only packets from addresses that 192.168.0.5 sends packets to.

Comment: *"Port 0's subnet might have a compromised machine on it."* That is, for the purpose of this study, another machine inside the NAT could be under the control of an attacker. The compromised machine would get its instructions from web pages (permitted by the NAT router's firewall) and in turn be sending these packets. This is of course not supposed to happen, but I want to be able to say, **the xyz service provides read-only access on this green cable and read-write on the yellow cable**, absolute end of sentence. I could of course just have two listeners, but I want to expand my learning also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Solaris, the ip_strict_dst_multihoming parameter will perform the anti-IP spoofing function you're looking for.  To quote, "by setting the parameter ip_strict_dst_multihoming to 0 the system drops any packets that appear to originate from a network attached to another interface ["Solaris Kernel Tuning for Security".](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/solaris-kernel-tuning-security)  So to answer your question: risk can be addressed by properly configuring the box not to forward spoofed packets.

Note that this addresses the simple case that you've outlined.  I don't think it will help in the case of routing multiple networks via multiple interfaces.  In other words, if you had a static route so that traffic for 192.168.2.0/24 was also routed over interface 1, then I'm not sure Solaris would drop a packet *from* 192.168.2.5 that came in on interface 0.  I think only the networks defined by interface 1's bound address will be dropped.

If you're looking on turning a Solaris box into a router, you should carefully read guides such as the link above.  Solaris is not, in my humble opinion, a great router system.  Solaris 11 did add the ipfw firewall, however, which brings closer to par with your average BSD/Linux box.  If you're going to route between networks of differing security levels, you should do it right and NAT and/or apply firewall rules.

Comment: I am not using static routes and I am not using Solaris as a router. The only routing instruction is in `/etc/defaultrouter` which is basically the default gateway for the internet side of things which happens to be on ethernet port 0.

Comment: +1 for the link. This will be helpful for our new standard server build. I will read it end to end when I have time.

Answer (score 3):

Though there may be ways to deal with this issue via the system kernel, it is also very easy to mitigate via other means.

Some tools would include IPS and firewalls.

A simple example of this would be via IPTables.  If you are working on a system that runs iptables, the following line should do the trick...

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

This also depends on your network environment, it's plausible that the way the network is configured simply does not allow for this to happen (routing/NAT/firewalls).

** *posted due to request* **

Comment: This was not as clearly worded as the original comments. But yes, software firewalls such as `ipfilter` are probably sufficient

Answer (score 2):

As the above post says, ip_strict_dst_multihoming parameter is what you want to prevent the INCOMING packet. That parameter is turned off by default, so you have to set it to '1' in order for it to work.

Assuming it's off, the outgoing packet will be sent out interface #1. The stack does not remember what port the packet came in on. All it knows is that it has a packet destined for an address 192.168.1.x. It doesn't know why it has the packet, where it came from, or even the contents. All it knows is the destination address, which means port #1.

Comment: +1 for "It doesn't know why it has the packet" :) But thanks, a direct answer to the question. I will be setting that flag anyway to achieve ideal behavior. This is a good second answer.